# How to fix website breaking the Android Webview?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I've came across a weird issue with the Android Webview. Loading the https://www.jiji.ng site breaks all webviews in the application. When this site is loaded, no other site can be loaded in any webviews in the application again. The progress just stops and nothing happens. Removing the old Webview and creating a new one doesn't work either. The webview only starts working after killing and opening the application again. It only happens when the Webview has JS and dom storage enabled.

Here's the code of the activity in a sample application I've created to demonstrate this issue:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val editText by lazy { findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input) }
    private val webViewContainer by lazy { findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.webviewContainer) }
    private val recreateWebviewButton by lazy { findViewById<Button>(R.id.recreateWebview)}
    private val progress by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.progress) }

    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
        webView = createWebview()
        webViewContainer.addView(webView)
        initEditText()
        initRecreateWebviewButton()
    }

    private fun initRecreateWebviewButton() {
        recreateWebviewButton.setOnClickListener {
            val oldUrl = webView.url
            webViewContainer.removeAllViews()
            this@MainActivity.webView = createWebview()
            webViewContainer.addView(webView)
            webView.loadUrl(oldUrl ?: "about:blank")
        }
    }

    private fun initEditText() {
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, i, _ ->
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                webView.loadUrl(editText.text.toString())
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun createWebview(): WebView {
        val webView = WebView(this).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
        }
        webView.settings.apply {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            domStorageEnabled = true
        }
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
                onProgressChange(newProgress)
            }

        }
        return webView
    }

    private fun onProgressChange(newProgress: Int) {
        if (newProgress < MAX_PROGRESS) {
            progress.isVisible = true
            progress.text = newProgress.toString()
        } else {
            progress.isVisible = false
        }
    }

    private companion object {
        private const val MAX_PROGRESS = 100
    }
}
```

The full application can be found here: https://github.com/kubak89/WebviewIssueExample

I suspect the issue is caused by some permanent internal state of the Webview engine being altered by the JS code, but I'd like to know if there's a workaround for this that could be implemented in Kotlin.

Comment: Look at the code closely in the main activity on the GitHub.. the dev has javascript enabled and code that you don't have. So maybe you need JavaScript enabled.

Comment: @CampNerd I do have JS enabled, it's the same code in here and on Github. I know this because I wrote this code.

Comment: when I get back to the house I will see if I can find a solution. So look for an answer at some point to day